# When using -Xmx flag, what happens if the argument given exceed physical memory?

Tags: java, jvm, paging, ram

When using -Xmx flag, what happens if the argument given exceed physical memory?

Also is there any way to explicitly make JVM to use a specific amount of memory using paging?

Comment: For the first question: The JVM will execute just fine. It might crash when it tries to allocate more memory than what is available, but it'll start up fine. Not sure if/how virtual memory plays into this. No idea about the second question.

Comment: Are you talking about a specific brand of JVM at all? They do differ in their memory handling implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See for yourself:

[image: Trying for a heap too large]

JVM fails in getting enough memory for the heap and exits.

I don't think there is a way to make JVM use a specific amount of memory for paging, but you can use:

`-XX:+|-UseLargePages`  --for large page support

and `-XXLargePageSizeInBytes=<n>`  --for specifying how large your large pages can be.

Look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/java.html