# What happens when -XMX argument tries to take most of the available primary memory?

Tags: java, out-of-memory

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130251/when-using-xmx-flag-what-happens-if-the-argument-given-exceed-physical-memory) I came to know if -Xmx argument exceeds the available memory of device then we would get an error.

[image]

Which is great, but I want to understand what will happen if I allocate say 70 % of my primary memory to JVM and program has just reached say 65 % and now the machine cannot allocate more memory to JVM since the memory is used. Will an `OutOfMemoryError`  be thrown ?

Comment: The JVM tries to preallocate most of the memory it needs to avoid this, but it can still happen. It is better to avoid working too close to the limit of your memory. e.g add a modest swap space to stop such errors.

Comment: But when that happens will it throw OutOfMemoryException ?

Comment: It throws an OOME after it has successfully allocated a Java Heap, and that heap is full after a Full GC.

Answer (score 0):

**I think it will OutOfMemoryError, Because -xmx 128m parameter tells JVM can use up to max 128MB memory for heap if memory free else throw Exception.**

Comment: Else throw Exception ?